# dropdown selected index code shortening

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a range of 10 dropdowns and labels that have and will get the same value. Is there another way to do this besides copying and pasting the same code 10 times?

```
protected void drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        lblPOLimit1.Text = "PO Med not Selected";
    }
    else if (drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        lblPOLimit1.Text = "0 / 0";
    }
    else if (drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        lblPOLimit1.Text = "8 / 20";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your question regarding the whole code snippet for 10 different drop downs? Or is it 10 different SelectedIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually place these kind of translation tables in Dictionary objects and move these Dictionary objects out of the method. This allows you to easily reuse these tables or replace them by another structure (e.g. a database store) at a later time.

```
class SomeClass
{
    static readonly Dictionary<int, string> INDEX_TEXT_TABLE = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 0, "PO Med not Selected" },
        { 1, "0 / 0" },
        { 2, "8 / 20" }
    };

    protected void drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblPOLimit1.Text = INDEX_TEXT_TABLE[drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex];
    }
}
```

By the way, you may want to look into using the semantically more meaningful `SelectedValue` property. Drop-down lists are generally key-value pairs with both key and value being of type string. So using this property is a more appropriate mapping between data and representation. This also improves the clarity of your code.

```
class SomeClass
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, string> VALUE_TEXT_TABLE = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "None", "PO Med not Selected" },
        { "Zero", "0 / 0" },
        { "EightTwenty", "8 / 20" }
    };

    protected void drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblPOLimit1.Text = VALUE_TEXT_TABLE[drpPOMedList1.SelectedValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Martin using arrays makes more sence. The key is just sequential integers.

Comment: Please review your code. What if `drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex` returns 0 ?

Comment: I've updated the mapping. `var` may not work in ASP.NET 2.0 because it's a C# 3.0 feature. Yes, you could also use other data structures such as a string array. The most important point of all this is to extract your business logic (repeated IF-THEN statements) and place it into a data structure.

Comment: is there a way to declare the Dictionary publically so that I can reference it for the other drpPOMedList_Selected Index there are 10 of them.

Comment: Sure. Just move the dictionary out of the method into a class variable. You can even move the dictionary to a static "Constants" class if you'd like. I've updated my original answer to reflect your new requirement.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you are saying. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a relation between texts, but faild. If you don't have a relation for texts, then use arrays or lists.

```
private readonly string[] arr = new string[] { "item 0", "item 1", ... }
protected void drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblPOLimit1.Text = arr[drpPOMedList1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: You can probably get a reference to the control from the sender or `EventArgs`, which would let you use the same event handler for all of the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Same delegate for all dropdownlist

```
protected void drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   ...
}
```

Associate this delegate to all dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownlist id="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />

<asp:DropDownlist id="ddl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpPOMedList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />

.......
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the items in a data structure (List/Array/Etc.) and edit as necessary.